# Multiples threads running on one core instead of four depending on the OS

Tags: linux, windows, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

I am using Raspbian on Raspberry 3.

I need to divide my code in few blocks (2 or 4) and assign a thread per block to speed up calculations.

At the moment, I am testing with simple loops (see attached code) on one thread and then on 4 threads. And executions time on 4 threads is always 4 times longer, so it looks like this 4 threads are scheduled to run on the same CPU.

How to assign each thread to run on other CPUs? Even 2 threads on 2 CPUs should make big difference to me.

I even tried to use g++6 and no improvement. And using parallel libs openmp in the code with "#pragma omp for" still running on one CPU.

I tried to run this code on Fedora Linux x86 and I had the same behavior, but on Windows 8.1 and VS2015 i have got different results where time was the same one one thread and then on 4 threads, so it was running on different CPUs.

Would you have any suggestions??

Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
//#include <arm_neon.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

float simd_dot0() {

unsigned int i;
unsigned long rezult;
   for (i = 0; i < 0xfffffff; i++) {
    rezult = i;
   }
 return rezult;
 }

 int main() {

 unsigned num_cpus = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();

 std::mutex iomutex;
 std::vector<std::thread> threads(num_cpus);
 cout << "Start Test 1 CPU" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
 double t_start, t_end, scan_time;
 scan_time  = 0;
 t_start = clock();
 simd_dot0();
 t_end = clock();
 scan_time += t_end - t_start;
 std::cout << "\nExecution time on 1 CPU: "
   << 1000.0 * scan_time / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << "ms" << std::endl;
 cout << "Finish Test on 1 CPU" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
 cout << "Start Test 4 CPU" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
 scan_time  = 0;
 t_start = clock();
 for (unsigned i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
   threads[i] = std::thread([&iomutex, i] {
     {
       simd_dot0();
                std::cout << "\nExecution time on CPU: "
                          << i << std::endl;

     }

     // Simulate important work done by the tread by sleeping for a bit...

   });
 }

 for (auto& t : threads) {
   t.join();
 }

 t_end = clock();
 scan_time += t_end - t_start;
 std::cout << "\nExecution time on 4 CPUs: "
      << 1000.0 * scan_time / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << "ms" << std::endl;
 cout << "Finish Test on 4 CPU" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
 cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
 while (1);
 return 0;
}
```

**Edit :**

On Raspberry Pi3 Raspbian I used g++4.9 and 6 with the following flags :

```
-std=c++11 -ftree-vectorize -Wl--no-as-needed -lpthread -march=armv8-a+crc -mcpu=cortex-a53 -mfpu=neon-fp-armv8 -funsafe-math-optimizations -O3
```

Comment: Could you specify the flags you have passed to gcc (and its version)?

Comment: On Raspberry Pi3 Raspbian  I used g++4.9 and 6 with  "-std=c++11 -ftree-vectorize -Wl,--no-as-needed -lpthread -march=armv8-a+crc -mcpu=cortex-a53 -mfpu=neon-fp-armv8 -funsafe-math-optimizations  -O3"